# Does an overall PHPunit Test Result of 0 or 1 (True / False) exist

Tags: php, phpunit

PHPunit can create a multitude of result reports, but I am having trouble figuring out how to get an overall result for all tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can check the exit status of the phpunit command
In your shell, try

```
phpunit successfulTest.php
echo $?

phpunit failingTest.php
echo $?
```

The result should be different.
I figured this out by remembering how the phpundercontrol guys wrote their [phpunit target](http://www.phpundercontrol.org/documentation/getting-started.html#phpunit-target)

Comment: That works as well as something like this:  exec('phpunit AllTests.php', $result = array(), $status);

$status contains the exit code.